# Why Facebook not show images and title when share URL

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

When using Facebook Sharer, Facebook will not shw the post title and image.

But I add open graph in my site and some post work good and some post not work good.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="thumbnail_image" />
```

in my facebook page we show post like :( http://prntscr.com/h7gwjl )

But I need to show like :( http://prntscr.com/h7gx7e )

Comment: use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ to debug or tell us what URL you are trying to share

Comment: i use it and i see this problem http://prntscr.com/h7nu0a

Comment: So what URL are you trying to share?

Comment: this
http://www.t-voice.net/blog/2017/11/07/قوقل-تركز-على-المميزات-الرئيسية-لبكسل-2/

Comment: Looks like it working now

Comment: yes today its work !, but if you see here (http://www.t-voice.net/blog/2017/11/08/شركة-صينية-تشتري-حصة-10-في-سنابشات/) its not work

Comment: This is what Facebook sees: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.t-voice.net%2Fblog%2F2017%2F11%2F08%2F%25D8%25B4%25D8%25B1%25D9%2583%25D8%25A9-%25D8%25B5%25D9%258A%25D9%2586%25D9%258A%25D8%25A9-%25D8%25AA%25D8%25B4%25D8%25AA%25D8%25B1%25D9%258A-%25D8%25AD%25D8%25B5%25D8%25A9-10-%25D9%2581%25D9%258A-%25D8%25B3%25D9%2586%25D8%25A7%25D8%25A8%25E2%2580%258C%25E2%2580%258B%25D8%25B4%25D8%25A7%25D8%25AA . And there is no og:image

Comment: but if you see my site , i add it and found in my site

Comment: But it is not what you send to Facebook when they scrape you

Comment: so there are problem,

Answer (score 0):

As Wizkid say you can use developers.facebook.com/tools/debug for debug your site. You will paste the url in debugger and facebook will clear the cache from your url. If this not work, i suggest you try install a plugin that do this for you.

You can try YOAST SEO. 
Here are an article about this.
https://kb.yoast.com/kb/getting-open-graph-for-your-articles/

Comment: Can you try disable your permalinks and test debug with this link? [link] http://www.t-voice.net/blog/?p=57248